# In Rummikub, can you split a run on the end or it must be within the ends? ex- 34567 turned into 234...&...567

Tags: rummikub

To me, it sounds as if the added tile must split the existing run (ex- 34567 to 345 567), not that a tile can be added to the start or end of a run & then split it apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 34567 is on the table and you have a matching 5, you can split into 345, 67 and add the 5 to the 67 to get 567.

If 34567 is on the table and you have a matching 2, you can add the 2 to get 234567. You can then split into 234 and 567, but you can also keep it a full set.